# Alignment in RTL Languages

Tags: html, css, browser, web, internationalization

I need to right-align a block in LTR languages, and left-align in RTL languages.  "text-align=end" works in all browsers except Internet Explorer.  What are some alternative solutions that work in all browsers?

Comment: because text-align:end is introduced in css3 so it won't work in IE8. you can fallback with text-align left/right as required by targeting IE browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it will work.

IN HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ar" dir="rtl">
```

CSS:

```
html[dir="rtl"] #navigation {
float: right;
display: inline;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 360px;
}
```